# How to select specific column indices from a matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a matrix and a list of column indices that I want to select from the matrix for each row. How can I do that in numpy?

```
my_matrix = np.array([[1, 2], [4, 5]])
col_idx = np.array([1, 0])
selected = .... # selects 1st element of row 0 and 0th element of row 1.
print selected
# np.array([2, 4])
```

Comment: `my_matrix[range(col_idx.size), col_idx]` should do the job.

Comment: @iluengo: that's more of an answer than a comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can slice using range:

```
In [11]: my_matrix[np.arange(my_matrix.shape[0]), col_idx]
Out[11]: array([2, 4])
```

Answer (score 2):

[`np.choose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html) is very useful for this making these sorts of selections:

```
>>> np.choose(col_idx, my_matrix.T)
array([2, 4])
```

And on a larger matrix:

```
>>> my_matrix_2 = np.array([[1, 2], [4, 5], [3, 7], [4, 1]])
>>> col_idx_2 = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1])
>>> np.choose(col_idx_2, my_matrix_2.T)
array([2, 4, 3, 1])
```

The method returns a new array with the selected values (not a view of the original array).

---

There are more examples of this (initially slightly non-obvious) method in the documentation, but I'll explain what's happening using the second example above.

We're using `np.choose` to return a new array from an array of choices called `my_matrix_2.T`, where `col_idx_2` specifies which row of the choice array we should pick from each time.

Notice we transpose `my_matrix_2` for this to work:

```
# my_matrix_2.T
array([[1, 4, 3, 4],  # row 0
       [2, 5, 7, 1]]) # row 1
```

We have `col_idx_2 = [1, 0, 0, 1]`. Now stepping through this array one value at a time:

- the *first* element of the new array will be the *first* element of row `1` of `my_matrix_2.T`. This is `2`.
- the *second* element of the new array will be the *second* element of row `0` of `my_matrix_2.T`. This is `4`.
- the *third* element of the new array will be the *third* element of row `0` of `my_matrix_2.T`. This is `3`.
- the *fourth* element of the new array will be the *fourth* element of row `1` of `my_matrix_2.T`. This is `1`.

Hence the method returns `array([2, 4, 3, 1])`.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [211]: M = np.array([[1, 2], [4, 5]])

In [212]: cid = [1, 0]

In [213]: M[[list(i) for i in zip(range(M.shape[0]), cid)]]
Out[213]: array([2, 4])
```